# Openshift NodeJS App 404 Not Found

Tags: node.js, openshift

I am creating my first node application on OpenShift.

I created an app with node 0.10 and MongoDb 2.4 but whenever I go to the application URL ,http://cm-justinbezanson3.rhcloud.com, it redirects to https://cm-justinbezanson3.rhcloud.com/app and says 404 Not Found.

I am sure I am missing a step somewhere.

Comment: hi, is your app up and running. I have also deployd nodejs app and it is working fine. Please deploy it again so that I can see whats the problem. Did u try adding a domain in openshift app because this problem happens due that.

Comment: I had tried and it is working fine. Are you guys still having same problem ?

Answer (score 0):

If you still having this problem, you can follow this tutorial to deploy nodejs on openshift.

https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLcdTDBNC_bSj1GG0_-K6R5_UgV9E3jBPZ

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.